# Socket.io not firing events from client to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

Why doesn't my server respond to an emitted event by the client? I have tried a few trivial examples from the socket.io webpage and they seem to be working fine.

My goal is to emit an event whenever a user focuses out from the input box, compare the input value on the server, and fire an event back to the client.

**client-side**

```
$('#userEmail').focusout(function() {
  var value = $('#userEmail').val(); // gets email from the input field
  console.log(value); // prints to console (it works!)
  socket.emit('emailFocusOut', { userEmail: value }); // server doesn't respond to this
});
```

**server-side**

```
io.sockets.on 'emailFocusOut', (data) ->
  console.log(data)
```

**Additional info**

- express 3.0rc4
- socket.io 0.9.10
- coffee-script 1.3.3

Comment: Can you post in the log that displays on your browser's Console (in Chrome)?

Comment: @Omkar: When I "focus out" from the e-mail input I get this printed in the console: email@email.com custom.js:47. But nothing happens on the Node.js console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need some answer from server your server should **emit** message back to client.
`console.log` does not do network answer.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('emailFocusOut', function(data) {
        data.receivedAt = Date.now();
        socket.emit('emailFocusOutResponse', data); // answer back
    });
});
```

Then on client you can listen for `'emailFocusOutResponse'` and handle this message.

Answer (score 6):

You have to put your custom event inside the `io.sockets.on` function. The following code will work:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {  
  socket.on("emailFocusOut", function(data) {
    console.log(data) // results in: { userEmail: 'awesome' }
  })
});
```